# CSS - How to pad an elements width by 50% of itself?

Tags: html, css, padding

### PLAYGROUND

How to pad an element by 50% of itself?

I want div `.B` to be **50%** the width of its container where `.A` has a variable width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">SOME TEST TEXT TO CHECK FOR LINE BREAK</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.A{
    background:#58c;
    min-width:300px;
    padding-right:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:300px;
}
.B{
    background:#b88;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I am unsure why in the demo div `.A` has padding 50% of its container instead of itself.

Comment: I need all content inside A to be padded so padding B would mean applying this class to every child element. Undesired.

Comment: What should the desired result look like?

Comment: Desired result: All children of .A are contained within the left 50% of the container .A

Comment: then why don't you make the childrens `width:50% ` ??

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qtb10h9b/3/?

Comment: Because their may be hundreds of nested children. I do not wish to apply a class to every child element. I suppose the obvious answer is to add an intermittent div between A and its children with width 50%.

Comment: then use the selector `.A > div`

Comment: @danko Imagine .A is the website wrapper that contains everything.

Comment: so ? It applys to all the direct div childrens ... so

Comment: div, ul, li, ol, input, select... and on and on...

Comment: and if you need on all direct childs then use `*`

Comment: * is very bad css, it would be very slow and inefficient.

Comment: just put .A inside a wrapper, and leave the padding-right of .A at 50%

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon :P post it as the asnwer resolves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qtb10h9b/8/)

Add a div after `.A` and before `.B` to contain all children.

Use margin-right instead of padding to simulate the same effect of 50% padding.

This will work even when `.A` has a variable width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="AB">
        <div class="B">SOME TEST TEXT TO CHECK FOR LINE BREAK</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.A{
    background:#58c;
    min-width:300px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:300px;
}
.AB{
    background:#b88;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As someone said (and as the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) say!) for padding (and also margins, of course):

> Percentages refer to the width of the containing block

So a solution here could be to put .A inside a wrapper, and leave the padding-right of .A at 50%

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper-A">
    <div class="A">
        <div class="B">SOME TEST TEXT TO CHECK FOR LINE BREAK</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper-A{
    width: 100%; // or pixels
    ...
}

.A{
    display: block;
    padding-right: 50%;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qtb10h9b/6/

Comment: Thanks lorenzo this will work but I already came to a similar conclusion below. I also needed the width of The wrapper to be variable.

Comment: 100% *is* variable. By the way, you can make it variable as you prefer, it'll work

Answer (score 0):

You essentially answered the question yourself, but didn't put it in your code:

When you said you wanted to pad 50% of the div of itself - there is no defined width for class "A".

```
.A{
    background:#58c;
    min-width:300px;
    padding-right:50%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:300px;
    width: 100%; // this was added
}
```

Comment: This will only work at width 100%. In this instance width is variable.

Comment: That could be turned into a variable, you just have to define it. Essentially, because you indicated this is a CSS/HTML question, you would get a response linked to that.